# Updating GUI Label as a new thread's deletage

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

How can you update the GUI when using a delegate function as new Thread? I am trying to update a label, that would tell the user the state of application's progress, but this way, it only updates once it is done, not while doing it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                int currentFile= 0;
                int allFiles = Source.FilePaths.Count;
                foreach (var path in Source.FilePaths)
                {
                    var file = new File(path, Source.DestDirPath, System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path));

                    file.saveSQL();

                    currentFile++;

                    int rounded = (int)((currentFile/ allFiles) * 100);

                    CompletionLabel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Completion.Text = "Completion: " + rounded + "%"));

                }
            })).Start();
        }
}
```

I would like to keep it as simple as possible, because it is just a simple converter, that converts some text file to sql files.

Comment: `int rounded = (int)(((double)currentFile/ allFiles) * 100);` ?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: 27/35 = 0,77..., *100 = 77 when you round it, the percent of the progress

Comment: What is the question? You always see `0 %` ?

Comment: When I am activating the process I see 0%, after it completed 100%. I think it only updates once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your problem is with integer division. To fix it you just need a cast to `double` or `float`. If you noticed my first comment, you'd have got the answer.

```
int rounded = (int)(((double)currentFile/ allFiles) * 100);
```

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. To determine the remainder of 7 /
>   3, use the remainder operator (%). To obtain a quotient as a rational
>   number or fraction, give the dividend or divisor type float or type
>   double. You can assign the type implicitly if you express the dividend
>   or divisor as a decimal by putting a digit to the right side of the
>   decimal point, as the following example shows

[From msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

Comment: When you commented the answer, I tried it in an online c# compiler, but I thought I used the (double) conversion too, so I copied your version. :)
Thanks anyway!